# PowerMock whenNew Problem On Spring Component Constructor

Tags: spring-boot, junit, powermock, powermockito, spring-boot-test

I have a Spring Service like below:

```
@Service
public class SendWithUsService
{
    private SendWithUs mailAPI;

    public SendWithUsService()
    {
        this.mailAPI = new SendWithUs();
    }

    public void sendEmailEvent(Dto data)
    {
        try
        {
            SendWithUsSendRequest request = new SendWithUsSendRequest()...;
            mailAPI.send(request);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
           ...
        }
    }
}
```

And my test code look like below:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PowerMockIgnore({"javax.net.ssl.*"})
@PrepareForTest(SendWithUsService.class)
public class SendWithUsServiceTest
{
    @InjectMocks
    private SendWithUsService sendWithUsService;

    @Mock
    private SendWithUs mailAPI;

    @Test
    public void sendEmailEvent_successfully() throws Exception
    {
        whenNew(SendWithUs.class).withAnyArguments().thenReturn(mailAPI);
        Dto emailData = ...;
        sendWithUsService.sendEmailEvent(emailData);
        ...
    }
}
```

In here, PowerMock whenNew method doesn't work. But when I call it outside of constructor like inside the sendEmailEvent method, it is triggered.

Is there a way to handle it?

**Works:**

```
public void sendEmailEvent(Dto data)
{
   this.mailAPI = new SendWithUs();
    ...
}
```

**Not works:**

```
 public SendWithUsService()
    {
        this.mailAPI = new SendWithUs();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved it like below:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PowerMockIgnore({"javax.net.ssl.*"})
@PrepareForTest(SendWithUsService.class)
public class SendWithUsServiceTest
{
    @InjectMocks
    private SendWithUsService sendWithUsService;

    @Mock
    private SendWithUs mailAPI;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {   
      whenNew(SendWithUs.class).withAnyArguments().thenReturn(mailAPI);
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void sendEmailEvent_successfully() throws Exception
    {
        Dto emailData = ...;
        sendWithUsService.sendEmailEvent(emailData);
        ...
    }
}
```